# Tags [driver] and [device-driver] appear to be redundant

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I am referring to:

[driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/driver) (~6200 questions)
and
[device-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-driver) (~1000 questions)

(also [drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drivers) is already a synonym of [driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/driver))

The first reads:

> Device driver or software driver is a computer program allowing
> higher-level computer programs to interact with a hardware device.
> This tag should only be used for questions related to driver
> development, as questions about finding or installing drivers are
> off-topic for Stack Overflow.

and the second:

> A device driver is a specialized software component (usually
> considered "system software") which allows a system to interact with a
> particular type or class of hardware device, such as a keyboard,
> serial port, disk drive, video display, memory controller, or other
> peripheral.

Which seem to basically say the same thing (in terms of defining what the tag is for).

I had always thought "driver" in the context of software was just shorthand for "device driver". Are there cases where that is not so?

If they can be synonymized, I suppose "device-driver" may be the better term, being  more specific / more properly named.

Comment: To me, the term "driver" can mean a middle layer between the device driver (eg KMDF) and the rest of software. I might be in the minority here and it's still ambiguous.

Comment: Unfortunately the driver tag is quite a mess. Loads of questions that belong on Super User, some Selenium Webdriver questions, some Spark Driver questions, database driver questions, and very, very occasionally an on-topic question that asks about device drivers.

Comment: @yhyrcanus But would you say that is a truly distinct meaning from device driver that warrants an own tag? E.g. isn't an expert in one probably also an expert in the other?

Comment: It might be that "driver" is too vague and should really be split into several other tags (device-driver being just one of them)

Comment: "E.g. isn't an expert in one probably also an expert in the other?" Not at all! Someone who writes a driver for Selenium in Java probably has no idea how to write a printer driver in C and vice versa. Same thing with database drivers. No hardware involved. "driver" is quite the ambiguous term, so splitting it up makes sense.

Comment: How exactly are you counting the number of questions? I'm seeing about 5.5k for [driver](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdriver%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3).

Comment: @cigien You're searching with `is:q` while OP isn't, but the number should be the same both ways. Is this a bug with SO search?

Comment: @oligofren Read which person I am addressing. Yes, selenium drivers are of course something different than device drivers.

Comment: @cigien all I did was click the tag links in the question here and read off the #s from there. e.g., at the moment for "driver" it says "6,165 questions"

Comment: `driver` has a synonym `drivers` with 659 questions. Apparently searching with `is:q` ignores synonyms (the math works out)... @cigien

Comment: @Tomerikoo Ah, that makes sense. I was confused by the numbers. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MegaIng I don't necessarily think that's true. In every place i've worked at, the "device driver" is done in like half a day, while the rest of the "driver" is something that you work on over the course of the development of the product, spanning months/years. For example, I've never needed to look at a kmdf driver until earlier this year, but i've worked on "drivers" for about a decade now. That being said, it's still totally ambiguous, and I'd say if you're making a kmdf/umdf driver, use those tags.